# xml to active record in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have this code:

```
<user> <first_name>Bob</first_name> <last_name>Smith</last_name></user>
```

How could this code be converted to a user class?

```
class User 
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name  
end
```

i've tried the following:

```
@user = User.new
@user.from_xml(xml_data)
```

but it shows me an error: the `from_xml` method is not there .

**How to convert xml to class object in ruby on rails?**

please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your class isn't making use of `ActiveRecord`; it's just a bare class. If you want to use `from_xml`, which is defined in the `ActiveModel` module, you need to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name  
end
```

If you don't want to use ActiveRecord::Base, you can just include `ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml` into your class; however, that relies on `attributes=`, which is defined in AR::Base, so we need to define that ourselves instead. The following appears to work, but I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
class User
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::Xml

  def attributes=(attrs)
    attrs.each {|name, val| instance_variable_set("@#{name}", val) }
  end
end

user = User.new
user.from_xml('<user> <first_name>Bob</first_name> <last_name>Smith</last_name></user>')
# => #<User:0x3bcc760 @first_name="Bob", @last_name="Smith">
```

Comment: My problem is converting xml to model in ruby on rails,whether it is active record or bare class

Comment: The error you're showing - `from_xml` not being defined - is caused by `User` not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`. You should not be getting that error if `User` is a proper `ActiveRecord` model. Are you?

Comment: You don't need to write the `from_xml` function. If you class is defined with `class User < ActiveRecord::Base` then the `from_xml` function will be available. It should Just Work.

Comment: but my problem is converting my xml into my own defined model rather than database related model,if you defined like active record we must create table in database

Comment: after how can i display user values in view

Comment: Any way you like. That strikes me as being a new question, if you're having trouble.

Comment: yes. I have a problem for loading xml with multiple child nodes and holds as list<user> in ruby on rails is it possible..

Answer (score 0):

Hash.from_xml("some xml") will convert the xml to a hash

```
hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
```

and from hash you can perform active record functionality on it.